# CSS bug - text displays in one line

Tags: html, css, calendar

Could some on with Firebug or other tool check out [this](http://calendar-plugin.com/demo-calendar/) page. Take a look at this small sidebar calendar :

[image]

Please try to click on some bold date and try to add larger text in event like this :

[image]

As you can see text is displaying in one line and you can see just small part of the text, it should be displayed in couple lines. Like this (I just hardcoded `</br>` tags in code to display this example) :

[image]

I have tried a different variations with css, but I cant fix it. Could some one please fix it (css) and post the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have set `white-space:nowrap` on line 305 in your CSS:

```
.ftcalendar-event div {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 8pt;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 10pt;
}
```